# How can I use MSMQ in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure, nservicebus, azure-service-fabric, msmq, azureservicebus

I have implemented a Proof of Concept in Azure Service fabric that uses Azure Service Bus as a message queue. I'm using nServiceBus within the application to send and respond to messages which makes it very easy to change from one queuing technology to another.

I'd like to know if it's possible to use MSMQ instead of Service Bus in Azure Service Fabric as the nodes that are created are just windows 2016 servers and I'm not sure I need something like Service Bus. It's a question I want to answer with my POC.

Does anyone know whether MSMQ is included in an Azure Service Fabric node or how I could turn it on and if it's a viable solution?

Comment: From what I understand, never tried though, sure, MSMQ can run in a Service Fabric container.  But...why?  Using MSMQ in a way defeats the purpose of running on Azure.  One huge issues is that any data is isolated to a specific instance meaning your freedom to provision/unprovision is now restricted.

Comment: Considering that Azure Service Fabric **can** and **will** move services between nodes, this is just asking for troubles as MSMQ is file system based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - MSMQ is not suitable for Azure Service Fabric.
MSMQ is store and forward technology. It's using local file system to persist messages and then forward to another machine. When Service Fabric is going to move service from one node to another, it will not move the file system along. Meaning you'll lose messages.

I would recommend to stay with Azure Service Bus unless there's a good reason you're looking for an alternative.

Comment: Thanks Sean, that's a good reason. Do you know if Service Bus encrypts the message data that it stores? I know it transmits the data securely but I'm not sure about it's persistence and the messages I'm talking about could be quite sensitive.

Comment: For those reading this and thinking... perhaps create a separate persisted drive, it looks like you can't configure it there without manual intervention which wouldn't work. See... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/02/09/changing-the-msmq-storage-location/